# Using a regex to replace an arbitrary number of characters

Tags: c#, regex, string

My current task is to take a string and transform it based on a series of rules. I am currently having an issue with the following:

When given a string of the form `"XYYX"`, I need to change it into a string of form `"XZZX"`. I must keep the X's in place (which I can do), but I need to replace each "Y" with a "Z". The catch is, I do not know ahead of time how many "Y"s the string will contain. Each "X" is one of a range of characters, which I've had to obfuscate.

I'm currently writing this in C#. I would prefer to use a regex for this transformation, as I've been told it would be preferable to keep it as a regex by the person in charge of me. Currently, I use the following:

```
Regex reg = new Regex("([X])Y+([X])");
output = reg.Replace(inputString, "$1Z$2");
```

This works great if I'm converting "XYX" to "XZX", but it will also convert "XYYX" to "XZX", which does not preserve the original number of characters in between the X's. I also need to ensure that "XYYXY" transforms into "XZZXY". I realize this is complicated, as I am trying to use a regular expression in a way that it may not be designed for.

So, here's the question: Is there a way to use a regex to identify an arbitrary amount of characters which lie between two well-defined (but possibly distinct) delimiters, then replace only those characters with the same amount of a different character?

Most of the other questions I've seen only deal with replacing multiple characters with a single other character, and that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Need "Y"s to be same chars or they can be different chars between delimiter?

Comment: Y's are the same character, and will be replaced by Z's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need a fully regex approach:

```
(X|(?!^)\G)Y(?=Y*X)
```

And replace with `$1Z`. See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(X%7C(%3F!%5E)%5CG)Y(%3F%3DY*X)&i=XYYXY%0D%0AXYX&r=%241Z).

**Explanation**:

- `(X|(?!^)\G)` - `X` or the end of the previous successful match
- `Y` - a `Y`
- `(?=Y*X)` - there must be zero or more `Y`s followed with `X`.

Another approach: matching and capturing `Y`s, and then just replace them all with `Z`s:

```
var s = "XYYXYX";
var res = Regex.Replace(s, @"X(Y+)X",
          m => string.Format("X{0}X",m.Groups[1].Value.Replace("Y", "Z")));
Console.WriteLine(res);
```

See the [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/jbSH9J)